# Unable to connect to local Docker host from Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, localhost

I have docker installed on my Windows 10 OS on my laptop. Also I have pulled the jenkins image and created a container out of it (Image: docker pull jenkins/jenkins:latest).

My jenkins is up and running on localhost:8080. Now I have installed Docker plugin within the Jenkins and then I Add a new Cloud to run my build against docker.

However, while giving the docker host URI as "tcp://localhost:2375" it is giving me Connection Refused
[image]

Debug Steps:

1. I have already made by docker server listening on port 2375
   [image]
2. I tried adding the host entry in C:\ProgramFiles\Docker\config\daemon.json
3. I tried adding an env variable DOCKER_HOST to "tcp://localhost:2375

But none of the above worked.

However, when I launch jenkins on my local windows machine instead of launching it from docker, it is able to resolve the Docker host URI.

Comment: When you run the Jenkins container, did you open the port like `-p 2375:2375`?

Comment: No I just opened the port for 8080 and 50000 as per the Jenkins documentation. Do we need to do this?

Comment: No you do not need to open the TCP port. Could you please verify the TCP value by executing the below command of docker:
docker-machine env

Comment: It will display you docker-machine environment variable just verify that once and let me know

Comment: It gives me error as Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists. how to set this variable